# Automatically writing data from Python dictionary to a very specific excel format

Tags: python, excel, dictionary, pandas

I have some data stored in a .csv file that is automatically read into a nested python dictionary. The code I already have will read any properly formatted file such that the dictionary is of the form `dict[experiment][variable]=value`.

My goal is to rewrite the data into a very specific format, namely:

```
Name    Experiment1                     
Notes                           
Componentnotes                          
Components  time    LR1R2   LR1R2_I    R1       R1_I       R2      R2_I
Values       0     1.69127  16.9127    271.087  2710.87    127.087  1270.87
            20     62.0374  356.28     146.54   2107.15    2.54022  667.147
            40     50.0965  451.149    146.061  1793.54    2.06075  353.535
```

Note that this is pasted from excel so `Experiment1` is in cell B2.

My code so far:

import pandas
import openpyxl

```
def write_experiment_files_template(self):
    alphabet=list(string.ascii_lowercase)#get alphabet for looping over later
    for i in self.child_experiments_dir: #loop over all locations for writing the properly formatted data  
        for j in self.data_dct.keys(): #loop over experiments
            name = j[:-4] #get name of experiment and use it as name in spreadsheet
            for k in self.data_dct[j].keys():
                components= self.data_dct[j][k].keys() #get variable names
                data_shape =self.data_dct[j][k].shape  #get dimentions of data (which is a pandas data frame)
                #write the easy bits into the excel workbook
                wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
                ws = wb.active
                ws['A1']='Name'
                ws['B1']=name
                ws['A2']='Notes'
                ws['A3']='Componentnotes'
                ws['A4']='Components'
                ws['B4']='time'
                ws['A5']='Values'
                #loop over variables and write the pandas data frame into the space for the values
                for l in range(len(components)):
                    ws[alphabet[l+2]+'4']=components[l] #plus 2 to account for time and headers
                    #loop over the space in the spreadsheet required for data input (B5:B35)
                    for m in ws[alphabet[l+2]+'5':alphabet[len(components)+1]+str(data_shape[0]+4)]:
                        m[0]= self.data_dct[j] #attempt to assign values
```

The above code does not do what I need it to and it appears I can't find a way to fix it. Does anybody  have any ideas as to how I can either fix my code or take another approach to properly formatting this data?

Thanks

Comment: I'd look at [string.format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), described in [PEP 3101](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/).

Comment: Paste the original data and what you expect properly unless we wont be able to understand